# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory in visual studio code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-iot-edge

I am facing the problem while creating edge solution in visual studio code.
Its showing below the error

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'c:\Users\#########\.vscode\extensions\vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-edge-1.24.1\assets\solution\.gitignore'`

Anyone has any idea what is wrong happening here?

Answer (score 2):

it means that the folder does not have a .gitignore file inside, navigate to that folder and create a .gitignore file and add config/ to it, save the file, reload the vs-code window and it should work, hope this helps

Comment: Thank for reply. 
I resolved by the same way you mentioned.